# Visitor visa application

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I applied for a visitor visa on behalf of my nephew, who's in Italy. This was refused as it states he did not disclose the fact he already had an application rejected. I thought the question meant had he applied from Italy before, so ticked no. When my nephew pointed out that he had applied for a visa when he was in Pakistan, I stupidly told him that of course the home office would be aware of this and not to worry. If they queried then we would clarify. They didn't query but outright rejected his application and as they thought he was trying to deceive them, he's had a ban put on for 10 years. It seems harsh for something that was a) my fault and b) a misleading question.

I can understand if we had changed his details then he could be accused of deception, but everything else was correct. What can I do, if anything? I feel so guilty that he will suffer from my stupidity.

Comment: Should we assume that the application was for a UK visa?  How old is your nephew?

Comment: It takes quite a bit to incur a 10-year ban, and a bad thing if it was for deception. The best recourse now is to [consult an immigration law practitioner](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/). BTW, it's not the ECO's obligation to call you and see if you meant what you indicated; their duty is to evaluable the integrity of what has been presented in the application. It's unlikely that your nephew would be coming to the UK anytime soon.

Comment: I would take Giorgio's comment as actionable advice: get a lawyer. However, your nephew could well have been refused for some other reason so you haven't done much additional harm. Now you have an excuse for a trip to Italy!

Comment: Also, are you certain he has been given a 10-year ban?  The normal course of affairs is to apply the ban on the second refusal, where the first refusal says that a future application *may* be refused under paragraph V3.7 (a) or (b).  It is the possible second refusal, *if* under that paragraph,  that leads to the ban.  If he *was* given a ban, then, that suggests that his prior refusal was also on grounds of deception.

Comment: He is 30. The only reason I wanted him to come over was as my daughter is ill and cannot travel. She's 13 and has mobility issues at the moment. She also suffers from depression so I thought this would help her.

Comment: Question 6.3 Have you ever been refused a visa for any country, including the UK? The written English in your question is flawless. It is not credible that you thought this question meant 'had he applied from Italy before'.

Answer (score 1):

In theory your could reapply or appeal with a competent immigration attorney (and pay a lot of money) and hope for a different result although the probability of success is minuscule.

In practice the viable option open to you/him is wait the ten years. Next time let him fill out his own application after all he is an adult, maybe with the aid of an immigration attorney.